# Concise code to perform action on every element, when need index

Tags: c#, linq, comparative-review, iteration

When I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3620605/199364), which has code:

```
linqObject.Where((obj, index) => {
  DoWork(obj, index);
  return true;
}).ToArray(); //MUST CALL ToArray() or ToList() or something to execute the lazy query, or the loop won't actually execute
```

My initial reaction was similar to Mark Sowul's comment:

> "Wastes memory (allocating a list or array) and risks bugs (if you don't call ToList or ToArray). Why?".

---

But on further thought, what is a concise approach, avoiding the downsides of the above?
My first attempt:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in someEnumerable) {
    DoWork(item, index);
    index++;
}
```

Compared to calling a Linq operator, that seems verbose, low-level. I'm defining and manipulating an index, whereas Linq has an Operator that "almost" does what I want - takes care of the index tracking for me.

Personally, I *would* write the explicit `foreach` loop - but maybe that is only because I've been programming a long time, and am comfortable with that syntax.

---

Is there a more concise solution, that doesn't have the downsides of the first version shown (Where / ToArray)?

I'm trying to get comfortable with encapsulating such stuff into methods, often by using `Action<>` or `Func<>`, which are newer [to me] than the style of programming that became my habit. So that instead of repeating similar snippets of code, I just call a method.

> As an aside, Linq is also newer than my habits. Linq is concise, but not in a way that I find helpful; I find loops clearer to read; a better separation of the aspects of what is happening. But I'm open to seeing situations where its expressive power is appropriate.
>   [OFF-TOPIC: In contrast, I spent some time with F#, and found it to be fantastic. I LOVE the combination of functional with OO; just not the way Linq jams a handful of functional constructs into C#'s syntax. But this question is about making good use of C#, so all advice is appreciated.]

I think this becomes:

```
public static void ForEachWithIndex<T>(IEnumerable<T> e, Action<int, T> a)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (T v in e) {
        a(index, v);
        index++;
    }
}
```

which might be used like this:

```
ForEachWithIndex(e, (int index, T item) => {
    // Do Work based on index and item.
});
```

Or if an appropriate "DoWork" method already exists, simply:

```
ForEachWithIndex(e, DoWork);
```

Comments?  Improvements, or alternatives?
Is there a way to use Linq more concisely/efficiently than in the original code sample?

---

NOTE: I did not make this an "extension method" on "IEnumerable", due to comments people made in stackoverflow threads regarding "ForEach" as a possible extension method: dislike of a syntax that looks similar to a Linq operator - which traditionally don't have side-effects - for a method that clearly DOES have side-effects; indeed is all about the side-effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> linqObject.Where((obj, index) => {
>   DoWork(obj, index);
>   return true;
> }).ToArray();
> ```

Never ever! This is the worst possible abuse of an API. I 100% agree with the comment.

---

> ```
> int index = 0;
> foreach (var item in someEnumerable) {
>     DoWork(item, index);
>     index++;
> }
> ```

Yes, this is the way it should be, although this can be shortened... keep reading.

---

> ```
> public static void ForEachWithIndex<T>(IEnumerable<T> e, Action<int, T> a)
> {
>     int index = 0;
>     foreach (T v in e) {
>         a(index, v);
>         index++;
>     }
> }
> ```

This is better but the naming is still quite wrong and the `Action` parameters are in the wrong order. They should be *incremental*. This means that `T` is always there so it should be first, then any other parameters may follow, like the index.

---

I'm not sure what's wrong with using normal loops where necessary but if you really want to encapsulate them then...

---

Try to be consistant with the LINQ API and don't invent new method suffixes like `WithIndex`. Use overloads instead. In fact you can implement it once and call the *core* method with other overloads.

Notice the order of `Action` parameters. It's consistant with current APIs. `T` first then *index*. There is also no explicit parameter checking because it uses an empty collection if the `source` is `null` and the `?` operator to not call the delegate if this one is `null`. You can also throw if you want.

```
public static class Loop
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T, int> action)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var item in source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()) action?.Invoke(item, i++);
    }

    public static void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        ForEach(source, (x, i) => action(x));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very informative. Particularly useful was your detailed explanation of why to pick the parameter order, and showing two related overloads. One question: why create an empty enumeration, given that the result will lead to no action anyway? I see that would be  a useful habit, if pipelining the result to another method that takes an enumerable, but in this case, I think parameter check would be more readable: `var i = 0; if (source != null) foreach(var item in source) action(item, i++);`

Comment: Re "using normal loops where necessary" - agreed, I wouldn't do this just to do it. And perhaps this case is so simple that it wouldn't make sense. I wanted to see the alternatives for this simple case, then I can extrapolate to other situations, where it is worth inventing a method, to "name" what is being done.

Comment: _why create an empty enumeration_ well, no particular reason, I just liked it this way ;-) but you're right, an `if` is equally good.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way of doing this with standard Linq is

```
enumerable.Aggregate(0, (idx, obj) => { DoWork(obj, idx); return idx + 1});
```

However, this is obviously a semantic abuse. IMO the best solution is a ForEach extension method. The argument against it seems to put purism above pragmatism, but I would argue that there's a purist case that if you're writing with a functional style you should use functional control structures.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate seeing how clean one can get with Linq - your solution avoids the issues with the original code. And I agree that is still semantic abuse. Would you say the ForEachWithIndex method I show is a good solution? You would do something similar, and make it an extension method?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I'd just call it `ForEach` and let the signature tell you that it's with an index, but yes.

Answer (score 2):

I think unless you're going to be using it a lot I would avoid creating a method. It hides the intention behind a unnecessary layer of indirection.

You could save a bit of work by taking advantage of the `Select` overload that provides the index:

```
foreach(var item in enumerable.Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v }))
{
    DoWork(item.Value, item.Index);
}
```

The anonymous type creation could be shortened further, to simply `(v, i) => new { i, v }`, but this might not be as clear.

Comment: Ah, thanks - that is a useful variant of Select. However, "new" means a small object is created for each element? I guess the only way to avoid that cost is to embed "DoWork" inside the Select - but the result would not be as readable, so never mind.